# What's the purpose of Django setting ‘SECRET_KEY’?

Tags: python, django, security, encryption

I did a few google searches and checked out the docs ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key ), but I was looking for a more in-depth explanation of this, and why it is required.

For example, what could happen if the key was compromised / others knew what it was?

Comment: If you have a secret key, and it's compromised and released to others, you have a problem. It doesn't matter if you're using Django or not.

Comment: But what problem, exactly?

Comment: I did a thorough answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170637/effects-of-changing-djangos-secret-key/15383766?noredirect=1#comment21743494_15383766) (shameless plug)

Comment: @sberder Maybe you should write an answer to this question as well. I imagine you could do it much better than the accepted non-answer.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It is used for making hashes.  Look:

```
>grep -Inr SECRET_KEY *
conf/global_settings.py:255:SECRET_KEY = ''
conf/project_template/settings.py:61:SECRET_KEY = ''
contrib/auth/tokens.py:54:        hash = sha_constructor(settings.SECRET_KEY + unicode(user.id) +
contrib/comments/forms.py:86:        info = (content_type, object_pk, timestamp, settings.SECRET_KEY)
contrib/formtools/utils.py:15:    order, pickles the result with the SECRET_KEY setting, then takes an md5
contrib/formtools/utils.py:32:    data.append(settings.SECRET_KEY)
contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py:112:        SECRET_KEY, modified to make it unique for the present purpose.
contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py:114:        key = 'django.contrib.messages' + settings.SECRET_KEY
contrib/sessions/backends/base.py:89:        pickled_md5 = md5_constructor(pickled + settings.SECRET_KEY).hexdigest()
contrib/sessions/backends/base.py:95:        if md5_constructor(pickled + settings.SECRET_KEY).hexdigest() != tamper_check:
contrib/sessions/backends/base.py:134:        # Use settings.SECRET_KEY as added salt.
contrib/sessions/backends/base.py:143:                       settings.SECRET_KEY)).hexdigest()
contrib/sessions/models.py:16:        pickled_md5 = md5_constructor(pickled + settings.SECRET_KEY).hexdigest()
contrib/sessions/models.py:59:        if md5_constructor(pickled + settings.SECRET_KEY).hexdigest() != tamper_check:
core/management/commands/startproject.py:32:        # Create a random SECRET_KEY hash, and put it in the main settings.
core/management/commands/startproject.py:37:        settings_contents = re.sub(r"(?<=SECRET_KEY = ')'", secret_key + "'", settings_contents)
middleware/csrf.py:38:                % (randrange(0, _MAX_CSRF_KEY), settings.SECRET_KEY)).hexdigest()
middleware/csrf.py:41:    return md5_constructor(settings.SECRET_KEY + session_id).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Why didn't they call it a salt then? ;)

Comment: This is a guess, but I suppose it is easier to tell people "don't share your `SECRET_KEY`", as opposed to "your `SALT` is a secret key that you should keep to yourself."

Comment: That distinction is very important. In cryptography, salts are not secret, but `SECRET_KEY` must be kept secure. The use of the `SECRET_KEY` is much more akin to the use of a key in a signed hash such as HMAC (which, if performance wasn't a consideration, would probably be used instead).

Comment: This does not look like an answer to me. All you did was a single grep command without explaining what any of it does. Where is the answer to "what could happen if the key was compromised?"?

Comment: Also since the SECRET_KEY is confidential, prefixing a SECRET to the key ensures that Django will encrypt/mask the values where ever needed.

Comment: @TravisJensen - wouldn't salts not being secret defeat their purpose?  It would be trivial to include a known salt in brute force attack along with a password hash dictionary.

Comment: @JamieMarshall for a brute force attack yes, but that is not the reason why hashes are salted. Their purpose is to combat the use of rainbow tables, instead of having to brute force a hash. In that case, it doesn't matter that the salt is public, since you'd still need to fully brute-force the hash using that salt. And if you are using a hashing algorithm that is brute forcible like md5 for security, then you have other issues that have nothing to do with the salt being public.

Comment: It's not used for passwords. Passwords use random generated salt for each account and PKGF hash by default. But it's used for other stuff, like generating password reset link, etc.. https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L206 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L280

Comment: `SECRET_KEY` is the signing key, but it is NOT a `salt`. [Django has a salt which is different than SECRET_KEY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/signing/#using-the-salt-argument).

Answer (score 88):

The [Django documentation for cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signing/) covers the uses of the ‘SECRET_KEY’ setting:

> This value [the `SECRET_KEY` setting] is the key to securing signed data – it is vital you keep this secure, or attackers could use it to generate their own signed values.

(This section is also referenced from [the Django documentation for the ‘SECRET_KEY’ setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY).)

The cryptographic signing API in Django is available to any app for cryptographically-secure signatures on values. Django itself makes use of this in various higher-level features:

- [Signing serialised data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signing/#protecting-complex-data-structures) (e.g. JSON documents).
- Unique tokens for a user session, password reset request, messages, etc.
- Prevention of cross-site or replay attacks by adding (and then expecting) unique values for the request.
- Generating a unique salt for hash functions.

So, the general answer is: There are many things in a Django app which require a cryptographic signature, and the ‘SECRET_KEY’ setting is the key used for those. It needs to have a cryptographically strong amount of entropy (hard for computers to guess) and unique between all Django instances.

Comment: "and unique between all Django instances." -- does this imply if say I have 3 webservers running the same Django app behind a load balancer I should have 3 distinct `SECRET_KEY` settings?

Comment: @AdamParkin, that sounds like a good start for [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), to get its own answer.

Comment: Great suggestion, done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657422/are-django-secret-keys-per-instance-or-per-app

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The first answer is ambiguous.

Answer (score 53):

[According to the Django Documentation on **`SECRET_KEY`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key):

> The secret key is used for:
>
> - All sessions if you are using any other session backend than **`django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache`**, or are using the default **`get_session_auth_hash()`**.
> - All messages if you are using **`CookieStorage`** or **`FallbackStorage`**.
> - All PasswordResetView tokens.
> - Any usage of cryptographic signing, unless a different key is provided.
>
> If you rotate your secret key, all of the above will be invalidated. Secret keys are not used for passwords of users and key rotation will not affect them.

Comment: Useful info regarding what happens if the `SECRET_KEY` is rotated. +1