# Are Django SECRET_KEY's per instance or per app?

Tags: python, django

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382149/purpose-of-django-setting-secret-key/47117966?noredirect=1#comment90264587_47117966) asks about the purpose of the Django `SECRET_KEY` value.  [One of the answers to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117966/808804) stated "It needs to have a cryptographically strong amount of entopy(sp) (hard for computers to guess) and unique between all Django instances."

This is a bit ambiguous: if I say for example have a single Django application deployed to multiple web servers behind a load balancer, should each have it's own distinct `SECRET_KEY`, or should the `SECRET_KEY` be shared amongst all instances?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the same Django application you should use the same `secret key` to ensure that the same client can properly use the service if the load balancer redirects his/her traffic mid session. Otherwise, surely undefined behavior will arise. More specifically, all these things would break:

- sessions, the data decode will break, that is valid for any session backend (cookies, database, file based or cache).
- password reset token already sent won't work, users will have to ask a new one.
- comments form (if using django.contrib.comments) will not validate if it was requested before the value change and submitted after the value change. I think this is very minor but might be confusing for the user.
- messages (from django.contrib.messages) won't validate server-side in the same timing conditions as for comments form.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170637/effects-of-changing-djangos-secret-key). As a side note, I completely agree that the `secret_key` aspect of Django feels dangerous and mystic, despite it being very explainable, and is not treated by the documentation with any sort of clarity.